# Drawing a half arrow with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Is there a command to draw upper half of an arrow in `tikz`? Something similar to:

[image]

Comment: Yes; see 16.3.5 in the PGF 3.0 documentation.

Answer (score 13):

This can be easily obtained via `arrows.meta` library in PGF 3.0. The shape you requested belong to the `Staight Barb` family (See PGF 3.0 documentation page 206). As a MWE, see this simple code and the output below it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-{Straight Barb[left]}] (0,0)--(0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output here is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a symbol from `latexsym` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\begin{document}

$\rightharpoonup$

$\rightharpoondown$

\end{document}
```

[image]